# How to set local time on Azure Web App service?

Tags: php, azure, time

The PHP application needs Asia/Kolkata local time. I have tried setting up WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE to 'Indian Standard Time' and TZ to Asia/Kolkata in [Application Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhLWS.png).

In SSH, when I type date command, it says Indian time but the time is nearly 6 hours and 30 minutes behind the actual local time.
How can I get the actual local time? The server location is US East.